# Python Script to refresh all excel files in a folder

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to automate some of my work.
I want to refresh all excel files in a specific folder.
Below is the script that I tried.

````
```
import win32com.client
import glob2
from pathlib import Path

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

directory = 'Y:\\path\\to\directory'

pathlist = Path(directory).glob('*.xlsx')

for path in pathlist:
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path)
    wb.RefreshAll()
    xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save()
    xlapp.Quit()
````

```
The above script refreshes the first excel file and then throws an error.
Error : Object invoked disconnected from its clients.
```

Answer (score 0):

You close client in loop `xlapp.Quit()`.

May solve issue.

```
import win32com.client
import glob2
from pathlib import Path

xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

directory = 'Y:\\path\\to\directory'

pathlist = Path(directory).glob('*.xlsx')

for path in pathlist:
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(path)
    wb.RefreshAll()
    xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
    xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save()

xlapp.Quit()
```

Comment: @fable changed the code as suggested. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this below code and it is not working. is something needed for accessing one drive folders. Just need to be able to refresh power queries.